# Set colors in colormap to specific index values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, colormap

I have multiple pictures with 8 bit indexed colors (0-255). In the end I want some of the colors at specific index values. Black has to be value 0 and white 255. Is there a possibility in ArcGIS to change the index position of colors? If not, maybe there is some different solution?

Comment: If I understand you well, you want to create a [colormap file](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-color-map-clr-file.htm)?
This way, you encode color easily.

Comment: I already have a colormap for my picture. I just want to switch some of the index values to another position without changing colors in the picture itself. For example: Currently white has the value 7 and black the value 132, in the final colormap I want them to have the value 255 and 0, but the actual colors have to stay.